# Accessing custom layout resources from cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, android-linearlayout, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to use LayoutInflater from my cordova plugin to replace a toast layout (adding a image to it) problem is that R.layout.custom_toast (to get custom_toast.xml file) gives error "error: cannot find symbol" and doesn't work. Where should i put, into the plugin folder structure, my custom_toast.xml file to access it from my plugin java code? there is any magic to get this working? why R is not working?

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));
```

many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

Since the plugin is not an Activity (do not extend activity) you cannot use the R directly. What you can do is instead of doing

```
R.layout.name_of_file
```

do this:

```
Application app=cordova.getActivity().getApplication();
String package_name = app.getPackageName();
Resources resources = app.getResources();
int ic = resources.getIdentifier("name_of_file", "layout", package_name);
```

So, the int ic will have the right indice of the "name of file" that is stored on R. So, instead of using     R.layout.name_of_file, simple use ic.

You also have to import these packajes :

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Resources;
```

Comment: How does this work for a layout.xml file in a Cordova Plugin where an R file is not generated?

Comment: hmmm, are you sure that is not generated? Are you including it on your project?